# TestNG Initialization Fail to Initialize Object

Tags: testng

I have an abstract class which contains the initialization logic of `@BeforeSuite` and `BeforeMethod`. A  `Client` object is initialized in the `@BeforeSuite` method and used in `BeforeMethod`. However, when I print out the execution order and the null check in both method, the execution order works as expected but the `BeforeMethod` reports the client reference is null, which doesn't make sense since `@BeforeSuite` already initialize it. Code sample and print result are provided:

```
public abstract class TestBase {
public Client client;
@BeforeSuite
public void suiteSetup() {
    client = initializeClient();
    System.out.println("BeforeSuite");
    System.out.println(client == null); // print false
}

@BeforeMethod
public void suiteSetup() {
    System.out.println("BeforeMethod");
    System.out.println(client == null); // print true
    client.call(); // Throw nullpointer exception
}
}

TestClass extends TestBase {
@Test
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and all works fine...

```
 public class Client {
        public void call() {
            System.out.println("CALL");
        }
    }

    public Client initializeClient() {
        return new Client();
    }

    public Client client;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void suiteSetupQ() {
        client = initializeClient();
        System.out.println("BeforeSuite");
        System.out.println(client == null);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void suiteSetup() {
        System.out.println("BeforeMethod");
        System.out.println(client == null);
        client.call();
    }

    @Test
    void clientTest() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
```

Stdout:

```
BeforeSuite
false


BeforeMethod
false
CALL


test
```